# What are my options for ensuring that water pressure doesn't drop in the top floors when taps in the lower floors are opened?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

In many multi-storied buildings, I've noticed that the water pressure in the top floor taps reduces drastically when the taps on the lower floors are open. 
I'm currently in conversations with the builder deciding on the plumbing for a house under construction. The water source is an overhead tank.

What options do I have for making sure that the water pressure in the top floor taps doesn't reduce when the taps on the lower floors are open?

Will separate outlet pipes from the overhead tank to each floor help?
If it is a single outlet pipe from the overhead tank, will reducing the diameter of the pipe as we go lower work?
The option being suggested by the builder right now is a pressure pump - is this the only option? I don't particularly like this because I trust gravity more than electronics, plus it feels like a waste of electricity as well.

Answer (score 2):

Separate outlet pipes would do it, but pressure on the top floor will always be lower than pressure on lower floors, as it's closer to the tank level.

Comment: Any opinions on the reducing diameter idea? Something along the lines of 2inch pipe from the tank - which splits into a 1 in pipe going into the top floor, and 1.5 in pipe going to the lower floor and so on.   The advantage I see with this approach is less pipes to lay, so should be cheaper.